# Xero Invoice API

Tags: xero-api

I need to sync invoice from my application to xero portal for that i had used invoice api which provided by Xero.

**Invoice API URL : https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices**

In xero invoice api tax and discount parameter available for lineitem (invoice item), but no option of tax and discount for order so, my application'invoice have tax and discount on full order.

can anyone help me how can i sync tax and discount on full order in xero invoice api ?

For reference i have attached xero invoice api parameter image.

[image]

Comment: Xero invoices calculate this on a per-line basis, not per-invoice as far as I am aware (and the documentation seems to back it up) so if you want to alter the figures I think you would need to do it pro-rata across each line, checking for rounding issues once you have don so. I ran into a similar issue where my system calculates tax per invoice, but I had to change it to match Xero and calculate line-by-line because I got some invoices that were a penny different because of rounding.

Comment: @droopsnoot Yes you are right, i need to do like that.